# form_for @item.subitem.new

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this form for uploading pictures.

```
<%= form_for Picture.new do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :file, "Upload Pictures: " %>
    <%= f.file_field :file, multiple: true, name: "picture[file]" %>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

I'm trying now to make a has_many connection between this model and another model called Item (Item has many pictures) and have one form for these two models.

I thought all I have to do is something like this:

```
<%= form_for(@item) do |f| %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :keywords %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :keywords %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>

 # and here goes the same form, just @item.pictures.new instead of Picture.new

<%= form_for(@item.pictures.new) do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :file, "Upload Pictures: " %>
    <%= f.file_field :file, multiple: true, name: "picture[file]" %>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

But with this form when I submit an image - it doesn't assign item_id to the Picture. (I do have has_many and belongs_to properly written).

Do I need to pass item_id manually? (don't think it's good idea cause then I'll need to make sure they're not trying to upload pictures to some items they don't own)

Comment: "Do I need to pass item_id manually?" << Yes. " I'll need to make sure they're not trying to upload pictures to some items they don't own" << Yes

Comment: ok, thx. wasn't sure if that's a good idea.

Comment: Aren't you missing the `multipart/form-data` attributes in your form?

Comment: It seems like Rails3 adds it. My HTML does have multipart/form-data

Answer (score 0):

just in case anyone is curious - I solved it by passing item_id to the picture like so:

```
<%= form_for Picture.new do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :file, "Upload Pictures: " %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :item_id, :value => @item.id %>
    <%= f.file_field :file, multiple: true, name: "picture[file]" %>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

and making sure in the picture model that current_user owns the item with this id.